# Images of JQuery SlideShow not always loading with correct size

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I added a JQuery SlideShow with 6 png images each with the size 548px X 320px

For some reason, sometimes when the page first loads these images appear very tiny.  When I refresh the page, the images appear normal size.   Again this doesnt happen every time.  Im not sure if this could be a JavaScript error because when I run this in JFiddle there are JavaScript errors from the plugin's js file.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/Re9pt/3/

[image]

I've noticed on other sites that they implement some type of PreLoad().  I dont have that.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="top-feature">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img alt="image1" src="images/slide1.png" />
        <img alt="image2" src="images/slide2.png" />
        <img alt="image3" src="images/slide3.png" />
        <img alt="image4" src="images/slide4.png" />
        <img alt="image5" src="images/slide5.png" />
        <img alt="image6" src="images/slide6.png" />
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#top-feature {
height: 320px;
width: 848px;
margin: 12px 0 0 16px;
background: orange;
/*padding: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
}

#top-feature div {
/*float: left;*/
}
.slideshow {
height: 320px;
width: 548px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
/*background: blue;*/
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @Myles, where do attach this? these .js files are huge to paste

Comment: @Paul if you can set up a http://jsfiddle.net that would be great!

Comment: @Paul, just put in absolute URL's in your code `http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg`

Comment: @Paul - Upload to http://imgur.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/Re9pt/

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there a way to upload js files to jfiddle?

Comment: FYI Im using jquery-1.4.1.min.js   ON jfiddle I only saw 1.3.2 and 1.4.3

Comment: @Paul you can point to files, not upload them, there shouldn't be that much difference between the minor JQ iterations, Click JSLint and fix those errors for a first ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I woulndt have a clue about how to fix those JavaScript errors.  They came with the plugin.

Comment: @mu is too short - I believe this could be a solution, and I havent been able to replicate the issue.  Do you want to post this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `width` and `height` attributes to the slideshow's `<img>` tags. IE might be losing track of how big the images are. Even if it isn't the problem specifying the dimensions in `<img>` tags is a good habit so it can't hurt.

Comment: There ya go, even though the height and width attributes were specified in the SlideShow CSS Function, those attributes werent specified in the Image Tag itself, so Im thinking that its correct that IE was loosing track of the Image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you are after?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/Re9pt/3/)

Comment: The images slide, but like I mentioned, sometimes when I load this in IE the 1 or some of the images appear like thumbnails.  I wasnt sure if I was missing something in the code like PreLoad, or I would need something like that.

Comment: It is defiantly not caused by not pre-loading I think it must be something in the JS...

Comment: If that were the case wouldnt this issue occur on every pageload?